# Can I remove this jack stud above our fireplace for recessed TV mount

Tags: framing, structural, construction, carpentry, remodeling

Can I cut/remove this jack stud above our fireplace to install a recessed TV mount without compromising the structure? Please see attached pictures.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Note that every TV installation guide will tell you that above a fireplace is one of the worst places to put a set. It's too high for most comfortable viewing (think front rows at the movie theater), and if you actually use the fireplace the heat and smoke will have adverse effects upon the set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes that stud can be removed. You can remove any or all of the center three. Just make sure you have good backing for the drywall.

As shown in the picture, there is no point load above it, and the stud is not resting on a header, so it cannot bear a load anyway.

Any of the studs supporting a seam of the OSB sheeting should not be removed. (So first inspect the sheeting right behind the stud of interest)

Comment: I wouldn't say "all". That would leave an extremely wide span for drywall. At least restore backing to roughly 24" intervals.

Comment: I would also comment that if the stud being considered for removal just so happens to be lined up on a seam between two sheets of the OSB exterior sheathing then it will not be a good plan to suggest removing it.

Comment: @MichaelKaras good point, edited.